# $G$ is a group, prove: if $[G: Z(G)]<∞$, then $[G, G]$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $Z(G)$ the center of $G$, and $[G, G]$ the commutator subgroup of $G$.  How do I show that if $[G:Z(G)]<\infty$, then $[G.G]$ is finite?

How to prove this? I cannot think of a good approach.

Comment: It is good form to include the question in the body of the post, even if you have asked it in the title.  I have edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A full proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108569/is-there-a-better-bound-than-n2n3-for-the-order-of-the-commutator-subgr). The one in the question comes from Passman's *The algebraic structure of group rings,* and the answer contains an improvement.

Answer (score 8):

Let $T$ be a transversal for $Z(G)$ in $G$, noting that $|T|$ is finite.  Then $[G,G]$ is generated by the commutators $[t_i,t_j]$, where $t_i,t_j\in T$.  Thus $[G,G]$ is finitely generated.

The transfer map from $G$ to $Z(G)$ is given by $g\mapsto g^n$, with $n=[G:Z(G)]$.  Since $Z(G)$ is abelian, $[G,G]$ is in the kernel, and hence for every $x\in [G,G]$, $x^n=1$.

Now $Z(G)\cap [G,G]$ has finite index in $[G,G]$; it is abelian, finitely generated, and has finite exponent.  It is thus a finite group.  Since it has finite index in $[G,G]$, $[G,G]$ is finite as well.

Comment: Why is $Z(G) \cap [G,G]$ finitely generated?

Comment: It is a finite index subgroup of a finitely generated group.

Comment: Can anybody say why $g\mapsto g^n$ is a group homomorphism?

Comment: @whacka see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_(group_theory)

Comment: @stewbasic can you explain why the transfer morphism is indeed $g\mapsto g^n$ ?

Comment: @Max The transfer map is independent of coset representatives, so choose a traversal of the form $\{g^it_j\mid 0\leq i<k,\,0\leq j<n/k\}$ where $k$ is the order of $g$ in $G/Z(G)$. Note that $g(g^{k-1}t_j)=t_jg^k$, so the image of $g$ is $(g^k)^{n/k}=g^n$.

Comment: @stewbasic : of course, thank you !

Comment: @MaximeRamzi alternatively, we only ever use that the transfer is $g \mapsto g^n$ on $Z(G) \cap [G, G]$ and for $g \in Z(G)$ this is immediate, regardless of the transversal.