# If $X$ is the set of all group elements of order $p$, and $X$ is finite, then $\langle X \rangle$ is finite

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated

> Suppose $G$ is any group and $X$ is the set of all elements of order $p$ in that group where $p$ is a prime. Prove that if $X$ is finite, then $\langle X\rangle$ is finite, where $\langle X\rangle$ is group generated by the elements of $X$.

If possible, I'm interested in a solution that assumes as few theorems as possible (aside from the well known ones of course).

Answer (score 5):

You may as well assume that $G = \langle X \rangle$. Since the elements of $X$ have only finitely many conjugates, their centralizers of in $G$ have finite index in $G$, and hence so does their intersection, which is $Z(G)$.

So $|G:Z(G)|$ is finite. There is a [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113438)  (which you would probably prefer to avoid using but for the moment I don't see how) that $|G:Z(G)|$ finite implies $G'$ is finite and then, since the result is clearly true for abelian groups, $G/G'$ is finite and hence so is $G$.

Comment: Why does having finitely many conjugates imply the centralizer has finite index?

Comment: The number of conjugates is equal to the index of the centralizer.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to prove this is by applying a classical result called *Dietzmann's Lemma* (for a proof see for example the book of Derek Robinson, [Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups, Part 1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NazwCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=dietzman%20lemma%20robinson&source=bl&ots=A3hmnOLaBl&sig=I1R5FSyBFdNY_luitI17pnxK7DE&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ57evo_jPAhXhCcAKHRGpBGkQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q=dietzman%20lemma%20robinson&f=false).) It implies that if you have a *finite set* $X$ in a group $G$, only containing elements of *finite order* and is *closed under conjugation*, then $\langle X \rangle$ is finite.