# When the subgroup generated by all elements of some fixed finite order equals the group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an infinite non-abelian group.
Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by all elements of order $n$,
for some fixed $n \geq 2$.

**My question:** Is it possible to tell when $H=G$? Namely, are there some known groups $G$ that are generated by all elements of some fixed finite order?

(It is easy to see that $H$ is normal in $G$, see [this](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/a-criterion-for-normalcy-of-finite-subgroups-2/); I do not know if this fact should help in answering my question).

**Edit:** The motivation for my question is [Proposition 5(b)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13370-011-0006-1), which seems to me too good to be true (perhaps I am missing some implicit assumptions in that proposition).
A relevant question is [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47591/what-is-the-subgroup-generated-by-involutions?rq=1).

Comment: you may wish to look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985031/if-x-is-the-set-of-all-group-elements-of-order-p-and-x-is-finite-then

Comment: Lagrange's theorem should give you some information

Comment: The gist of it it is that the set of elements of a finite order is normal in $G$ so we must have the subgroup generated by these elements as finite by Dietzmann's lemma, hence $H$ is never $G$ for $G$ infinite.

Comment: @EvgenyT, thanks for the reference!; however, in my case $X$ is not necessarily finite-- perhaps I was not clear enough.

Comment: Regarding whether there are known groups like this: The infinite dihedral group $G = <s,t | s^2 = t^2 = 1>$ is infinite non-abelian and generated by its order 2 elements (since the generators are among them).

Comment: Examples certainly do exist.
Having some non-trivial elements of finite order is certainly necessary. (This is called having torsion, or not being torsion-free.)
Among torsion-free group, being simple is then sufficient. (Because of the normality of the generated subgroup.)

Some interesting examples are given by Tarski monsters:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

In these groups, every non-identity element has the same order, so they satisfy your property in a very strong way!

Comment: @HughDenoncourt, nice example, thanks!

Comment: @verret, indeed interesting examples, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your question a bit: which groups $G$ admit surjection from a free product $\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z \,* \dots \mathbb * \, Z / n\mathbb Z \twoheadrightarrow^f G$? If you restrict it a bit and assume that $f$ induces isomorphism on abelianisations and $H_2(G, \mathbb Z) = 0$, then (by beautiful Stallings theorem) $f$ induces isomorphisms on *all* lower central quotients, and this is rather restrictive property.

In other direction, if you know that $G$ is nilpotent, then torsion elements form a normal subgroup, so if your group is simultaneously nilpotent, finitely generated and infinite, it cannot be generated by torsion even normally.

Third aspect is that if your group is finitely generated and *equals* its $n$-torsion (is subject to relation $x^n = 1)$, then it's finite for $n =$ 2 (obvious), 3 (easy lemma), 4 or 6 (not easy, but can be proven by elementary methods), and it's not known if it must be finite for $n$ = 5, 7, 8 $\dots$, 664 [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem)

Lastly, very plentiful source of natural examples are reflection groups in homogeneous spaces with most well-known case of [plane Coxeter groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will have to read it more carefully in order to understand all the details in it. (Please, do you think that the proposition that I have mentioned in the edit is indeed true?).

Comment: I've looked through the paper, but didn't get through, I'm not familiar with this area.

Comment: Statement 5b is actually not that striking, 5a is more interesting, because for any element $a \in G$ $<a>[<a>, G] \subset <a>^G$ and in perfect group you can expect that groups of this type will be relatively large.