# Number of elements of order $p$ in a (possibly infinite) group

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

If a group is finite, then it's easy to see by group action that $n_p\equiv-1\pmod p$.

However, is the result true for an infinite group? My conjecture is that if $n_p$ is non-zero and finite, then $n_p\equiv-1\pmod p$ of infinite groups. I proved the result for $n_2$, but don't know whether it is true for all primes.

Comment: To be clear, $n_p$ is the number of elements of order $p$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor yes

Comment: The deleted answer of @HallaSurvivor is actually correct. If there are only finitely many elements of order $p$ then they generate a finite subgroup $H$. $C_p*C_p$ is not a counterexample, because it has infinitely many elements of order $p$. To see that $H$ is finite, note that its centre has finite index, and so (by a result of Schur)  $[H,H]$ is finite, but $H/[H,H]$ is also finite.

Comment: @DerekHolt -- I've made my answer community wiki. Would you mind elaborating on your comment slightly in an edit? I'm not sure I follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a group with finitely many elements of order $p$.  We may assume that $G$ is generated by its elements of order $p$ (otherwise, just look at the subgroup they generate).  Since every conjugate of an element of order $p$ has order $p$, each element of order $p$ must have centralizer of finite index.  So, the intersection $Z$ of the centralizers of elements of order $p$ is finite index.  Since $G$ is generated by its elements of order $p$, $Z$ is actually the center of $G$.

So, the center of $G$ has finite index.  This implies that the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is finite (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108569/is-there-a-better-bound-than-n2n3-for-the-order-of-the-commutator-subgr) for instance).  But $G/[G,G]$ is an abelian group generated by finitely many elements of finite order, so it is finite as well.  Thus $G$ is finite, and so the result for finite groups applies.

Comment: Side remark: The argument works equally when the set of elements of order $p$ is replaced with any finite conjugacy-invariant subset $S$ consisting of elements of finite order, to show that $\langle S\rangle$ is finite.

Answer (score 6):

We know that the result is true for finite groups (by the group-action argument you're familiar with).

But if there's only finitely many elements of order $p$, we can look at $H$ the group generated by those elements. It is finite, and contains all the elements of order $p$. So the result holds for $H$, and since $H$ has *all* the elements of order $p$, the result holds for $G$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

*Added by Derek Holt*: proof that $H$ is finite. Since $H$ is generated by the elements of order $p$ and there are only finitely many, they have only finitely many conjugates, so their centralizers have finite index in $H$. So the intersection of their centralizers, which is the centre $Z(H)$ of $H$ has finite index in $H$.

Now, by a result of Schur, the derived group $[H,H]$ is finite. Since $H/[H,H]$ is an abelian group generated by finitely many elements of order $p$, it is also finite, and hence $H$ is finite.